# Must use a CNAME record to associate a domain name with RDS DB instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-route53

In the [official AWS Doc for Route 53 related to RDS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-rds-db.html), there is a special note of this:

> You must use a CNAME record to associate a domain name with an Amazon RDS DB instance. Route 53 doesn't support using other types of records for this purpose.

However, I could not find an explanation of why there is such a restriction, which seems to apply to only RDS, but not to other AWS services (such as S3 or EC2).  Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 7):

There are only three types of DNS resource records that might support a database such as RDS. A, A-ALIAS and CNAME.

An A resource record requires an IP address. This is a bad idea to use IP addresses for managed services. The simplest reason is that the IP address can change at any time.

An A-ALIAS resource record is not supported by AWS for RDS. A-ALIAS resource records are typically used for AWS resources that also point to the root domain (example.com). RDS does not need this type of record.

The only option left is CNAME. This is the recommended DNS resource record for RDS.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  However, I am not sure about your explanation about A-Alias cannot be used for RDS.  I can find an example of using A-Alias for S3 (i.e. not RDS) for a non apex zone (e.g. `acme.example.com`, where `example.com` is the apex zone) here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/RoutingToS3Bucket.html  It seems that only RDS is a special case, for some reason which is still not known to me.

Comment: S3 can be used for a zone apex. RDS cannot be used for a zone apex - technically it could but it would not make sense as RDS does not respond on port 80 or 443 in a way that convention expects. I am not saying that AWS cannot support A-ALIAS for RDS. AWS has chosen not to because it is not necesary. For example load balancers grow and shrink dynamically. Therefore the pool of IP addresses for load balancers changes - sometimes very quickly. A-ALIAS is a benefit as these changes are tracked automatically.

Comment: RDS endpoints do not change in a similar way. RDS is not a special case - most AWS services do not support A-ALIAS. The only services that support A-ALIAS are ELB, CloudFront, S3, EB, API Gateway, VPC endpoint.